# What's the correct pronunciation of 思 in と思つ?

Tags: pronunciation

In [this](https://images2-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=focus&gadget=a&no_expand=1&resize_h=0&rewriteMime=image/*&url=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XvKkWCJ3Yuc/WWYPpibT4GI/AAAAAAABIUU/8AlZE1I23I0rTGzz89s0NwKRj2YkzyglgCHMYCw/s0/image005.jpg) manga, 思 is being pronounced as おもう.

However, on [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%A4%E3%82%88), I'm getting *shita*. (In the same sentence: *かわいいと思うよ.*)

Why is this?

Comment: **One** kanji has many ways to pronounce it. For example: **読**む is pronounced **yo**mu, but **読**書 is pronounced **doku**syo.

Comment: There are **two pronounce systems** in Japanese Language. One of them it's called 音読, another is 訓読.

Comment: @QING So the Google Translate version is showing the 音読 version by mistake? Both are the same sentence.

Comment: Maybe not a mistake, You have to take a look into the context and previous character is.

Comment: In this sentence(your manga), it should be おもう.

Comment: I made a mistake. **読**書 is pronounced **doku**sho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistyping 思う. It's pronounced おもう ("omou").

かわいいと思うよ。 means "I think it's cute!" (The よ indicates certainty, conviction, or emphasis.)

Comment: Thanks for spotting that typo. However, the pronunciation of the phrase in the manga is still different from the one in Google Translate.

Comment: @alex: Uh... No it's not? The image you linked shows the exact same furigana for 思う. Or do you mean the mistyped version you put in Google Translate causes a different pronunciation than the actual word?

Comment: Oh, I think when I typed 思つ Google translate used the other pronunciation *shita*. Anyway, thanks. You answered my question!

Comment: What よ stands for is not certainty or conviction on your side but gap of recognition between the speaker and the listener, in other words, consideration for how the listener doesn't really believe so. When you compare the one with よ with the one without, the one without it sounds more decisive because it doesn't really care what the listener thinks.